# Installing PeaZip. Need Nautilus Scripts Folder for Context Menu Addition. Where Is It?

Tags: gnome, scripts, nautilus, 7zip, nautilus-script

[The instructions](https://peazip.github.io/peazip-free-archiver.html#linux_file_archiver) for PeaZip seem to say that, if I want PeaZip to appear in the Nautilus context menu, I should copy a specified PeaZip program folder to the system's Nautilus scripts folder. The instructions and other sources seem to think I should be able to find that scripts folder by right-clicking anywhere in a Nautilus window and choosing the option to Open Scripts Folder.

My context menu offers no such option. [One source](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1857) suggests that it has gone missing. [Linuxtopia](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_desktop_guides/gnome_2.14_user_guide/gosnautilus-440.html) seems to think the explanation is, rather, that "If you do not have any scripts installed, the script menu will not appear." [Another source](https://code.google.com/archive/p/linuxsleuthing/wikis/UsingNautilusScripts.wiki) says that I can always view the scripts folder by using this Nautilus menu option: File | Scripts | Open Scripts Folder. But my version of Nautilus doesn't have a menu, though I wish it did.

Really, I just want to use PeaZip. But since I seem to be taking the long route there, and have moreover gotten rather lost on that long route, I thought I had better stop and ask directions.

Comment: ehm it uses gtk2. what Ubuntu do you use? and why not the portable version? https://peazip.github.io/peazip-portable.html

Comment: Would a portable version be more likely to install a context menu entry? The PeaZip webpage says the portable makes no changes to the operating system. This is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Not sure how GTK2 is crucial here; by all means, help me understand.

Comment: I found a partial answer. For the individual user, I think the desired location is ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts. I'm not sure, so I'm not posting it as an answer. For the system, I wasn't able to find an answer. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2022/06/21/peazip-in-ubuntu/